# Deserializing JSON objects as List<type> not working in HTTPHandler

Tags: java, ajax, serialization

I am facing problem while deserializing to below entity using Javascript Serializer. Please help

JSON String:

```
{"AccountNo":0,"EmailAddress":"test@gmail.com","Destination_Prefernce":[{"Value":"Test Data"}]}
```

Java Code

```
public class EMailPreferenceEntity
{
private int _accountNo;
private string emailAddress;
private DestinationPreferences _destinationPrefernce = new DestinationPreferences();

public int AccountNo
{
    get { return _accountNo; }
    set { _accountNo = value; }
}

public string EmailAddress
{
    get { return emailAddress; }
    set { emailAddress = value; }
}

public DestinationPreferences Destination_Prefernce
{
    get { return _destinationPrefernce; }
    set { _destinationPrefernce = value; }
}

}
```

Handler File:

```
public class AjaxHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string jsData = context.Request["Data"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsData))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        EMailPreferenceEntity jsEntity = ser.Deserialize<EMailPreferenceEntity>(jsData);            
    }
}
```

Comment: If you serialize the entity, what does it look like?

Comment: are you sure that this is Java?

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure means your List will just become List after compilation so, when your http request arrives, it will try to deserialize List, and probably won't hit whatever you registered for List.

I'm not sure how your serializer handles it, but in Gson's case, you create a TypeToken out of the generic, so that the connection between type and serializer doesn't get lost after compilation.